# MongoDB return True if document exists

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, tornado-motor

I want to return true if a userID already exists and false otherwise from my collection.I have this function but it always returns `True`.

```
def alreadyExists(newID):
    if db.mycollection.find({'UserIDS': { "$in": newID}}):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

How could I get this function to only return true if a user id already exists?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> **Note:** This answer is outdated. More recent versions of MongoDB can use the far more efficient method [`db.collection.countDocuments`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53005106/9297144) by Xavier Guihot for a better solution.

`find` doesn't return a boolean value, it returns a [cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html). To check if that cursor contains any documents, use the cursor's `count` method:

```
if db.mycollection.find({'UserIDS': { "$in": newID}}).count() > 0
```

If `newID` is not an array you should not use the `$in` operator. You can simply do `find({'UserIDS': newID})`.

Comment: I would only add to this answer to include a projection with only the '_id':1 set so as the DB doesn't return an entire object, every ms and byte counts :)

Comment: Limiting result set to 1 with .limit(1) might be another valuable hint to the database

Comment: @Konstantin So use find_one() instead?

Comment: Oh, find_one() doesn't take a projection.  find() it is!

Comment: This is inefficient. For performance I suggest using 'count_documents' as stated in Xavier's answer.

Answer (score 49):

Starting `Mongo 4.0.3`/`PyMongo 3.7.0`, we can use [`count_documents`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents):

```py
if db.collection.count_documents({ 'UserIDS': newID }, limit = 1) != 0:
  # do something
```

Used with the optional parameter `limit`, this provides a way to find if there is at least one matching occurrence.

Limiting the number of matching occurrences makes the collection scan stop as soon as a match is found instead of going through the whole collection.

---

Note that this can also be written as follow since `1` is interpreted as `True` in a python condition:

```py
if db.collection.count_documents({ 'UserIDS': newID }, limit = 1):
  # do something
```

---

In earlier versions of `Mongo`/`Pymongo`, `count` could be used (deprecated and replaced by `count_documents` in `Mongo 4`):

```py
if db.collection.count({ 'UserIDS': newID }, limit = 1) != 0:
  # do something
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This reply should be the first one in the list!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Motor, find() doesn't do any communication with the database, it merely creates and returns a MotorCursor:

http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/motor_collection.html#motor.MotorCollection.find

Since the MotorCursor is not None, Python considers it a "true" value so your function returns True. If you want to know if at least one document exists that matches your query, try find_one():

```
@gen.coroutine
def alreadyExists(newID):
    doc = yield db.mycollection.find_one({'UserIDS': { "$in": newID}})
    return bool(doc)
```

Notice you need a "coroutine" and "yield" to do I/O with Tornado. You could also use a callback:

```
def alreadyExists(newID, callback):
    db.mycollection.find_one({'UserIDS': { "$in": newID}}, callback=callback)
```

For more on callbacks and coroutines, see the Motor tutorial:

http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html

If you're using PyMongo and not Motor, it's simpler:

```
def alreadyExists(newID):
    return bool(db.mycollection.find_one({'UserIDS': { "$in": newID}}))
```

Final note, MongoDB's $in operator takes a list of values. Is newID a list? Perhaps you just want:

```
find_one({'UserIDS': newID})
```

Comment: How to write this in Mongo Shell? Make Mongo Shell return boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
return db.mycollection.find({'UserIDS': newID}).count > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner solution in mongodb query

```
db.mycollection.find({'UserIDS': { "$in": newID}}).count() > 0 ? true : false
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
result = num.find({"num": num}, { "_id": 0 }) 
if result.count() > 0:  
   return
else:
   num.insert({"num": num, "DateTime": DateTime })
```